# StatsExchange - low friction, API-based statistics generator

Tags: discussion

I'm not 100% sure this is going to be on topic, so I apologize in advance if I'm doing the wrong thing.  However, I think this app may be of interest to people who are interested in statistics and Stack Exchange, and this seems to me like the best way to evangelize it :)

I wanted to let you folks who are major stats geeks know that I've been working on a Stack Exchange API app that can perform queries against Stack Exchange sites to gather question and answer data.  I run some really simplistic statistics against the data, which I find to be useful from time to time when trying to back up an assertion about the way people use the sites.

You can find it on StackApps [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/3180/statsexchange-low-friction-api-based-statistics-generator).

This is similar to the way Data Explorer works, except for a) it's live data (ie, no month delay) and b) there's no requirement to be able to use or understand SQL.  Due to the limitations of the API, I can't do as many cool things right in your browser as Data Explorer, but if you want something with a bit less of a learning curve that operates on live data, you might be interested in this.

Today I added the ability to export the data gathered from a given query to a CSV format, which means it can be imported into the data analysis tool of your choice.

Feel free to provide feedback on StackApps, or you can come and corner me on Chat (you'll find me in Gaming rooms most often, as I'm a moderator there).  My background is in computer engineering and not statistics, so what I'm passing off as "stats" here is probably pretty simplistic by comparison to what I see you guys doing.  Still, I welcome feedback and feature requests.